# In GitHub, is there a way to search for specific text in a particular team?

Tags: github

I'm currently inside an organisation in GitHub, which is divided into several teams. I have previously used the GitHub search bar to search for specific text inside a repository, and after starting to use GitHub Enterprise I also started searching by organisation as well.

However, in some scenarios I don't want to search inside the whole organisation, but only inside content owned by a particular team. I tried the syntax below:

```
org:<ORG> team:<TEAM> <text to search>
```

Which isn't referenced in any docs that I looked so far, but I got the result below:

[image: GitHub search error: " is not a valid team name."]

Which make me think that is actually possible to do some searching based on a team, since the error was about the team's name, and not about the search syntax.

So, is there a way to search based on a team? If so, how should I do it?

Answer (score -1):

In order to search with the `team:` or `team-review-requested:` filters you need to use the team's full name, which would be in the format of <org>/<team>, see GitHub's docs on [using search to filter issues and pull requests](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/tracking-your-work-with-issues/filtering-and-searching-issues-and-pull-requests#using-search-to-filter-issues-and-pull-requests). In your example, the following query should work:

```
org:<ORG> team:<ORG>/<TEAM> <text to search>
```

Comment: I tried to use it, but then I got no results, even though I know that my team has code that should appear in that search. If I try to do the same search without specifying a team, the results appear, together with results from other teams. Looks like to me that GitHub is considering "team:<ORG>/<TEAM>" as plain text.

Did you get any luck with it?